# Why math.sqrt in python doesn't work in my sublimeREPL?

Tags: python, sublimerepl

I have written this code in sublime text

```
if intentos<3:
    solution= math.sqrt(number)
    print("La raiz cuadrada de " + str(number) + "es" + str(solution))
```

Then I have used sublimeREPL and I don't know why but It has appear this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prueba.py", line 23, in <module>
    solution= math.sqrt(number)
NameError: name 'math' is not defined
```

This error only appears when I use math.sqrt and I don not understand why. Moreover, I have copied this exact code from a video tutorial and he does the same as me but for some reason his sublimeREPL works correctly.

Comment: Try adding ```import math``` at the beginning.  You need to import a module before you use it.

Comment: oh I didn't know that. It has work. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It gives the error `name 'math' is not defined` because you haven't defined `math`.

You need to import it using:

```py
import math
```

at the start of the program.

Read more in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)

Answer (score 1):

You miss an import of the math module, please try to add the line at the beginning of your script

```
import math
```